# Share sqoop incremental last value between two jobs

Tags: sqoop

I have a sqoop job that records incremental last value to do incremental appends through out the day.  My problem is that my directory changes each day so we can create partitions based on log_date.

I need to record --last-value through out the day.  Then I need to pass that value into a newly created job for the next day.  Is it possible to call a method to get last-value?

My current sqoop job looks like this written in a shell script.

```
sqoop job --create test_last_index \
-- import --connect jdbc:xxxx \
--password xxx \
--table test_$(date -d yesterday +%Y_%m_%d) \
--target-dir /dir/where/located \
--incremental append \
--check-column id
--last-value 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You need not call a method for the sqooping that you are doing. All you need to do is create a sqoop job and save it. Add the paramenters --check-column , --incremental  and --last-value  in the sqoop job that you create. The --last-value will be picked up with each consecutive run and will be retained in the job. Then you can use a --exec command to run the job periodically and also sqoop merge to merge the modified/appended data with the historical data.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I have developed sqoop script for Incremental Import as follows.

```
sqoop import 
--driver com.sap.db.jdbc.Driver 
--fetch-size 3000 
--connect connectionURL 
--username test 
--password test 
--table  DATA 
--where YEAR=2002 
--check-column TIMESTAMP 
--incremental append 
--last-value "2016-06-22 12:31:37.0" 
--target-dir  "/incremental_data_2002/year_partition=2002" 
--fields-terminated-by "," 
--lines-terminated-by "\n" 
--split-by  YEAR 
--m 4
```

Now, the above script is getting executed successfully.

In the above script i have hardcoded the `--last-value as "2016-06-22 12:31:37.0"`. when new data comes to source table in RDBMS again i am checking the last-value in the table and modifying the sqoop script manually with the value. Instead of that what i wanted here is that i need to have `--last-value` dynamically without hardcoding in sqoop script file.

Answer (score 0):

Sadly, Sqoop is not incorporating an automatic last value retrieving.

In the sqoop [documentation](https://sqoop.apache.org/docs/1.4.1-incubating/SqoopUserGuide.html)

You should use:

> At the end of an incremental import, the value which should be specified as --last-value for a subsequent import is printed to the screen. When running a subsequent import, you should specify --last-value in this way to ensure you import only the new or updated data. This is handled automatically by creating an incremental import as a saved job, which is the preferred mechanism for performing a recurring incremental import. See the section on saved jobs later in this document for more information.